# Confusion in sentence formation consisting participle clause

Tags: participle-clauses

I have written some sentences to demonstrate my skills in writing participle clause. Later,my friend whom I have given these sentences replied that these sentences are confusing and wrong. But I can not be sure why they are wrong.

To me, sentences which have same subjects are eligible for writing a participle clause.

1. Government,the decisions has already been revoked,are trying to take another new decisions.
2. Women have been contributing a lot for economic success, often deprived by the society.
3. Women have often been deprived a lot by society, contributing for economic success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend is right and these sentences are confusing and grammatically incorrect.  At this point in your English studies it might be best to follow simple patterns when trying to use more difficult grammar.  As you learn how native speakers use this grammar you can get more creative, but first you have to understand the basic forms:

> My friend lost his voice.  My friend can't play his concert.
>   **Having lost his voice,** my friend can't play his concert.
>
> I am very sleepy.  I will go to bed early.
>   **Being very sleepy**, I will go to bed early.

You can do this with the more complicated structures in your examples, but I think this will be difficult for you since these require you also establish the correct relationship between the two parts of the sentence.  For example, are they *complimentary*:

> We have been to the park.  Now we will go to the zoo.
>   **Having been to the park**, we will **now** go to the zoo.

Or are they *contradictory*?

> I only have a little bit of money saved.  I am still planning to take my girlfriend to an expensive restaurant.
>   **Having only a little bit of money saved**, I am **still** planning to take my girlfriend to an expensive restaurant.

Your examples are confusing because they fail to establish the basic relationship between the clause and the main sentence.  So to make them work I would need to add more information:

> The government has had many of its decisions revoked.  The government is going to try new strategies.
>   **Having had many of its decisions revoked**, the government is going to try new strategies.
>
> Women have contributed a lot to the country's economic success.  Nevertheless, women often feel society deprives them of their rights.
>   **Having contributed a lot to the country's economic success**, nevertheless women often feel that society deprives them of their rights.

Again, I would suggest you start with simpler topics and then work up to more complicated sentences like these.  Otherwise it will be difficult for people to understand what you want to say.

Comment: I have read some grammar books. based on that learning, I have written some sentences. could you please help me to get whether these sentences are wrong

Comment: 1.Even though women have been contributing to the economy, having been deprived by the society.
2. women are keeping the sign of success everywhere,being induced by various inducements from the government.
3. having been addressed early, tista problem could not have been existent.@andrew